# How can I set the color of the page (body) to the variable color of an element loaded in with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'd like to sync a container's background color to its child. Thanks

Here's what I tried, doesn't work...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var color = $("section").css( "background-color" );
  $('body').css("background-color", color);
});
</script>
```

Here's my Jquery AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPage(id) {
$('#output').html('<img class="loader" src="/assets/img/loader.gif" />');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_page.php",
        data:'id='+id,
        type: "POST",
        ;}
    });
}
getPage(1);
</script>
```

And my html...

```
<body>
<div id="output">
    <section style=";">
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </section>    
</div>
</body>
```

And the working solution from Shomz's answer!>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateColor();
});

function getPage(id) {
$('#output').html('<img class="loader" src="/assets/img/loader.gif" />');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_page.php",
        data:'id='+id,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);updateColor();}
    });
}
function updateColor(){
    var color = $("section").css( "background-color" );
    $('body').css("background-color", color);
}
getPage(1);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post HTML please ?

Comment: You aren't using any ajax...

Comment: looks like your function is fired once page loads but never when some ajax updates it later . function works but not for the intended purpose ;)

Comment: The code you have posted will fire on page load once.  It will never fire again until you load the page again.  Ajax does not causes page the reload so your color change will never occur.  Place your js code into a function and then call the function upon successful completion of your ajax.

Comment: I added missing bits above, thanks for your answers guys!

Comment: This selector : $("section") does not seem to be correct. It's neither id selector nor class.

Comment: The "get_page.php" returns a chunk of HTML from a database – among them also a <section> element and a <body>... Sorry if that wasn't obvious.

Comment: @MaheshChavda It is not an ID nor a class name - it's a tag name. Nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the color change code you call in the document ready callback in the AJAX success callback as well. Ideally, you could turn it into a function, and call it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateColor();
});

function getPage(id) {
$('#output').html('<img class="loader" src="/assets/img/loader.gif" />');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_page.php",
        data:'id='+id,
        type: "POST",
        }
    })
    .done(function(){
        updateColor();
    }
    // or just .done(updateColor)
}

function updateColor(){
    var color = $("section").css( "background-color" );
    $('body').css("background-color", color);
}
```

I don't see the code where you're updating your HTML from the AJAX response data, but I assume that's all good and your new `section` has a background color defined.

Comment: Here's what I came up with using your answer. EDIT: Updating up top

Comment: Yup, that's it. Btw. no need to repeat my answer in your question as it will stay here forever.

Comment: Thanks again, I really wasn't expecting such a quick response that did exactly what I wanted. I'm new here if you hadn't guessed :-)

Comment: You're welcome, mate, SO is a great place most of the time! Oh, and welcome aboard! :)